Netlify unable to process SSL/TLS certificate, I think it's due to client's domain
I made a website for a mutual's business. She has not paid me. Her site is live but is "not secure" due to the domain she purchased. I have tried meeting up with her to resolve this issue but she bails last minute. I feel like this is her responsibility to resolve due to her domain being the issue. I have completed the work we agreed too.
Here's the backstory: Client purchased the domain from Google Domains and then signed up for SquareSpace to attempt building out her own website. She didn't have the time to build it out so when we met she asked me to build her one using the same domain. I have built the website and it is live. However, I am unable to pass the SSL/TLS certificate on Netlify. I believe it is due to SquareSpace now owning the domain. I have the DNS configured on Netlify and updated the nameservers on her SquareSpace.
Message on Netlify: We could not provision a Let's Encrypt certificate for your custom domain.
Is there any way I can resolve this? Should I have the client purchase a new URL or purchase and SSL cert? Is this my responsibility? The site is live and functioning.
